# removing lines from a file

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

I've got the following code but it doesn't seem to be working.. anyone have any ideas why? basically I'm creating a new file containing all the lines except those which contain the two strings I'm trying to remove but the code doesn't seem to be working.

```
public void removelines(String name, String email){
try{
    //Create objects for our file and the temp file.
    File f = new File("addy");
    File temp = new File(f.getAbsolutePath()+ "temp");
    //Our readers.
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("addy"));
    PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(temp));

    String line = null;

    while ((line = buf.readLine())  != null) {
        //put all data not equal to that to be removed into the new file.
            if(!line.trim().equals(name) || !line.trim().equals(email)){
                print.println(line);
                print.flush();
            }
            }
        print.close();
        buf.close();
        f.delete();
        temp.renameTo(f);
    } catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR:" + e );
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does non-equality check of one variable against many values always return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-does-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-return-tr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your || needs to be an &&.

i.e.

```
!line.trim().equals(name) && !line.trim().equals(email)
```

Otherwise if the line isn't equal to either of name or email, it will be written.

Answer (score 1):

This will always be true:
"Name" != "Name" || " "Email" != "Name"

```
if(! (line.trim().equals(name) || line.trim().equals(email)) ){
}
```