# Not Equal to(!=) operation not working in while loop

Tags: python, loops

Are there any special rules in regards to using the != operation in a while statement in python. For example I have a loop of code like this

```
input("f_l value ")
while f_l != "s" or f_l != "S" or f_l != "q" or f_l != "Q":
    print("Error")
    input("f_l value ")
print("your f_l is correct")
```

The while loop won't stop and print the value. I don't know why. Any ideas?

Comment: You are not assigning to `f_l`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute block if a variable is not one of some specific values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/execute-block-if-a-variable-is-not-one-of-some-specific-values)

Comment: `or` should be `and`.

Comment: you can also reduce to `f_l.lower() != "s" and f_l.lower() != "q"`

Comment: @sam2090, or even ```if f_1.lower() not in ('s', 'q'):```, or ```if f_1.lower not in 'sq':```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're *not* assigning the return value of `input()` to `f_l`, so, how may it contain the required value? You should do something like this:

```
f_l = input('f_l value')
while f_l != 's' or f_l != 'S' or f_l != 'q' or f_l != 'Q':
    print('Error')
    f_l = input('f_l value')

print('your f_l is correct')
```

Now, that *will* still loop forever. Why? Because *nothing* can be `'s'`, `'S'`, `'q'`, and `'Q'` *at the same time*, because that's what you're expressing with the `or`s as the condition for the loop to finish. Maybe you want to replace them with `and`s?

```
while f_l != 's' and f_l != 'S' and f_l != 'q' and f_l != 'Q':
```

Now, that works, but it's still not optimal. You're checking for *every possible* input value, rather than simplifing yourself and doing something like:

```
while f_l.lower() not in ['s', 'q']:
```

Comment: @saulspatz: Eh... That's exactly what I said, no? **Edit**: Sorry, I didn't understood your comment's first sentence. May you clarify it a bit, please?

Comment: You're right;  I somehow just skipped over that paragraph when I read your answer.  Sorry.