# How do I use the boolean operator OR in a while loop

Tags: python

I have been struggling to troubleshoot a program, and I believe it comes down to this statement:

```
while line != '\n' or '':
```

I am reading a file using readline() and I'm struggling to fix the code in my function. 
For this while loop, I want it continue with these conditions:
- line is not equal to '\n'
OR
- line is not equal to ''

Why doesn't this statement represent the above situation?

Comment: Canonical similar question: [Execute block if a variable is not one of some specific values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/execute-block-if-a-variable-is-not-one-of-some-specific-values).

Comment: Do you just want read a file in Python? Why don't use `for` on the `file` object (actually, that called [`io.IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#i-o-base-classes)) or use [`file.readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines)? Relate: [Python: read file line by line into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array).

Answer (score 3):

You have to read

```
line != '\n' or ''
```

as

```
(line != '\n') or ''
```

The empty string evaluates to `False` in a boolean context, so your expression is equivalent to

```
line != '\n' or False
```

which is equivalent to

```
line != '\n'
```

You either need to write the expression like @houcros suggested, as

```
line != '\n' or line != ''
```

or as I would suggest, as

```
line not in ('\n', '')
```

which I think is easier to read. In your particular case, for this particular program, a simple

```
while line.strip()
```

would suffice, too - if `line` consists only of whitespace (check if that is what you *actually* want), `line.strip()` will be `''`, which evaluates to `False` as already mentioned.

Comment: `while line.strip()` is not the same as `while line != "\n"`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham nobody claimed that it is. I reminded the asker to double check if the `line.strip()` solution still does what he wants to do before using it, reminding him that `line.strip()` will return `''` if the line consists of whitespace only.

Answer (score 2):

While you say you want "`line` is not equal to `'\n'` OR `line` is not equal to `''`", I think you really want "`line` is not equal to `'\n'` AND line is not equal to `''`".  Otherwise, your condition is trivially true (because `line` cannot both be equal to `'\n'` and be empty).

Therefore, I believe the condition you are looking for is:

```
while line != '\n' and line != '':
```

or equivalently,

```
while not (line == '\n' or line == ''):
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be

```
while line != '\n' or line != '':
```

Comment: It's an infinite loop.