# What is Wrong With My Code That do...while Loop is Not Closing When Condition is Fulfilled

Tags: c++, do-while, libstdc++

I am working through *Ivor Horton's Beginning Visual C++ 2012*, and I am doing exercise two in chapter three: *Decisions and Loops*. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char letter;
    int vowels = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a letter, and enter q or Q to end" << endl;
        cin >> letter; // Enter a letter
        switch (letter)
        {
            case 'a' || 'A' || 'e' || 'E' || 'i' || 'I' || 'o' || 'O' || 'u' || 'U': // If letter is a vowel, add to vowels variable
                vowels++;
                break;
            default: // If letter is not a vowel, break loop
                break;
        }
    } while (letter != 'Q' || letter != 'q');

    cout << "You entered " << vowels << " vowels.";
    return 0;
}
```

The intended purpose of this program is to allow the user to enter a letter until they enter q or Q, at which point the do...while loop ends and the program displays to the user the number of vowels they entered.

When I run this, the program does not quit when I enter Q or q. Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: `letter` is never equal to both `'Q'` and `'q'`

Comment: Not what you asked (so posting as a comment), but `case 'a' || 'A' || 'e' || 'E' || 'i' || 'I' || 'o' || 'O' || 'u' || 'U':` means the same thing as `case '\1':` and doesn't check for vowels.

Comment: "*Loop is Not Closing When Condition is Fulfilled*" is a bold claim; suggesting the compiler is not generating your code correctly.  Occam's razor should always suggest  your code is at fault. In fact the condition *always* true.  A better title would be "Why does the loop never meet the terminating condition?" i.e. "*Why am I wrong?*" rather the "*Why is the compiler wrong?*"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`letter != 'Q' || letter != 'q'`

means...

letter is not `Q` `or` is not `q`... so it's always true... as if it's `Q`, it will not be `q`, and if it's `q`, it will not be `Q` ... that would be only false, if letter would be `Q` and `q` at once.

Just use:

`letter != 'Q' && letter != 'q'`

Comment: `('Q' || 'q')` -- That doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 2):

De Morgan's laws.

```
!( letter == 'Q' || letter == 'q' ) <=> ( letter != 'Q' && letter != 'q' )
```

De Morgan's laws states,

`Not (A or B)` is equivalent to `Not A and Not B`.

Answer (score 1):

`letter != 'Q' || letter != 'q'`

That's always true. You mean &&.

And NB for the `case` : it doesn't work as is, you could write `case 'a': case 'A' ... :`
=> all the vowel cases would fall to the `vowels++;`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char letter;
    int vowels = 0;
    int flag = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a letter, and enter q or Q to end" << endl;
        cin >> letter; // Enter a letter
        switch (letter)
        {
            case 'a' || 'A' || 'e' || 'E' || 'i' || 'I' || 'o' || 'O' || 'u' || 'U': // If letter is a vowel, add to vowels variable
                vowels++;
                break;
            case 'q' || 'Q' :  flag = 1;    
            break;
            default: // If letter is not a vowel, break loop
                break;
        }
    } while (flag !== 1);

    cout << "You entered " << vowels << " vowels.";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1.  That's not how you write multiple cases in C or C++.  2.  You appear to be trying to test for 'a' and 'Q' rather than 'q' and 'Q'.  3.  Your formatting is horrible.

Comment: It's still not how your write multiple cases in C or C++. (But thanks for fixing the other issues.)