# Using OR operator in a jQuery if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, operators

I need to use the OR operator in a jQuery if statement to filter out 10 states. My code works wile only excluding one state, but fails when I try to include multiple states. Is there a correct way to do this?

Code I am using :

```
if ((state != 10) || (state != 15) || (state != 19) || 
    (state != 22) || (state != 33) || (state != 39) || 
    (state != 47) || (state != 48) || (state != 49) || 
    (state != 51)) 
   return true;
```

Comment: you probably mean and?

Comment: @aw04 Yes! using the AND operator worked. I should have tried this before i posted this question. The other answers were good to know, but this was the easiest possible solution. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does non-equality check of one variable against many values always return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-does-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-return-tr)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Think about what

```
if ((state != 10) || (state != 15) || (state != 19) || (state != 22) || (state != 33) || (state != 39) || (state != 47) || (state != 48) || (state != 49) || (state != 51))
```

means. `||` means "or." The negation of this is (by DeMorgan's Laws):

```
state == 10 && state == 15 && state == 19...
```

In other words, the only way that this could be false is if a `state` equals 10, 15, and 19 (and the rest of the numbers in your or statement) at the same time, which is impossible.

Thus, this statement will *always* be true. State 15 will never equal state 10, for example, so it's *always* true that `state` will either not equal 10 or not equal 15.

Change `||` to `&&`.

Also, in most languages, the following:

```
if (x) {
  return true;
}
else {
  return false;
}
```

is not necessary. In this case, the method returns `true` exactly when `x` is true and `false` exactly when `x` is `false`. You can just do:

```
return x;
```

Answer (score 5):

The code you wrote will always return `true` because `state` cannot be both 10 and 15 for the statement to be false. `if ((state != 10) && (state != 15)....` `AND` is what you need not `OR`.

Use [$.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) instead. This returns the index of the element in the array.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/v42ty3e2/)

```
var statesArray = [10, 15, 19]; // list out all

var index = $.inArray(state, statesArray);

if(index == -1) {
    console.log("Not there in array");
    return true;

} else {
    console.log("Found it");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this is a fine alternative and all, but you don't even mention the problem with the code posted... this answer will likely only confuse the OP

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** using `.indexOf()` to detect if `stat` value is one of `arr` elements

**Pure JavaScript**

```js
var arr = [20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100];
//or detect equal to all
//var arr = [10,10,10,10,10,10,10];
    var stat = 10;

if(arr.indexOf(stat)==-1)alert("stat is not equal to one more elements of array");
```

Comment: this answer seems entirely overly comlex when the problem is a simple logic error

Comment: Updated to be sample using `indexOf()`

Answer (score 1):

The logical OR '||' automatically short circuits if it meets a true condition once.

false || **false || true** || false = **true**, stops at second condition.

On the other hand, the logical AND '&&' automatically short circuits if it meets a false condition once.

**false && true** && true && true = **false**, stops at first condition.