# What is the diffrence in using "or" instead of "and" in line 3?

Tags: python

```
permission = str(input("Would you like to take a quiz?\n")).lower()

if permission != "yes" and permission != "sure":
    print("Aww okay, maybe next time?")
    exit(0)
else:
    questionAnswer = input("Great! Do you know what keyword if and else make together?\n").lower()
    if questionAnswer == "elif":
        secondQuestion = input("Correct! Now, what does print do?\n").lower()
    else:
        secondQuestion = input("Incorrect, what is a integer?\n").lower()
    # noinspection PyUnboundLocalVariable
    if secondQuestion == "it prints a statement":
        print("Correct! You scored 2/2 on this test.\n")
    elif secondQuestion.lower() == "a whole number":
        print("Correct! You scored a 1/2 on this test.\n"
```

When I change the "`and`" in the start of the if, then no matter what I input I get back
"Aww okay, maybe next time?"

When i tried to switch my "Or" to an "and" it worked though? I don't understand...

Comment: Quite difficult to answer this non-tautologically. Maybe draw out the truth table to explain it to yourself.

Comment: Are you familiar with what the words "and" and "or" mean?  Are you familiar with boolean logic and how `if` conditions work and what that means?  It's not really clear where you're stuck on this.  In general, yes, changing the logic of the code can and often does result in observing different behavior from that code.  Specifically to this case, when you use `or`, can you think of any possible value which *doesn't* satisfy that `if` condition?

Comment: @jonrsharpe is right, it would be best for you to look into boolean logic/arithmetic so that you get a deep understanding of *and*, *or* and *not* ... Maybe this link helps as a starting point: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boolean-search/

Comment: Give `permission` a distinct value, like `"yes"`, then ask yourself what `"yes" != "yes" and "yes" != "sure"` means, compared to `"yes" != "yes" or "yes" != "sure"`. Try the same experiment with `permission == "sure"`, `permission == "no"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if a != "yes" and a != "sure":
        # This requires both conditions to be True.
        # Meaning a can be neither "yes" nor "sure"

    if a != "yes" or a != "sure":
        # This requires at least one condition to be True.
        # Meaning it is tautology
        # Always true since if a = "yes" it surely is not "sure" and otherwise
```

**EDIT:**

Let's make it more humanunderstandeable.

**Situation A** 
If you say **"I cannot say Yes and I cannot say Sure"**, this is `a != "yes" and a != "sure"`

**Situation B** 
If you say **"I cannot say Yes or I cannot say Sure"**, this is `a != "yes" or a != "sure"`

The thing is in **Situation A** you know that if you don't say "yes" and "sure" you will get permission.

In **Situation B** you know that if you don't say "yes" or "sure" you will get permission. So if you say "yes" you actually didn't say "sure" so you get permitted. If you say "sure" you did not say "yes" so you get permitted. If you say anything else than "yes" or "sure" you will get permitted. This is tautology.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an **and**, than both values must be true.
So basically, it checks if either of "yes" or "sure" is set.
if both are **not** set, you get the error message.

Using **or**, only one of both needs to be true.
So if you enter "yes", than "sure" is not set and vice versa.
So one of the conditions is always `true` and you get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not correct and I suspect it is due to a lack of theory knowledge. I would recommend using the negation of the `in` operator using when requiring a variable be with in certain set of values. I.e, instead of `if permission != "yes" and permission != "sure"`, use `if permission not in {"yes", "sure"}`. This will also make you code more dynamic for if you want to include more pass conditions in the future, like "accept" or "true".

If you want to purely use the basic camparison operators, then here are the basics:

- In python all variable have an inherit 'truthyness' associated with them determined by their `__bool__` method.
- `or` returns the first variable, `var`, where `bool(var)==True`. If `or` fails to find a varibale that evualtes to `True` it will return the last variable it evaluated.
- `and` return the first variable, `var` where `bool(var)==False`. If `and` failed to find any variable that evaluate to `False`, it will return the last variable it evaluated.
- NOTE: the explanations I gave for `or` and `and` are how they are defined when chaining them.
- NOTE: I mentioned `__bool__` so you are aware the all variable in python can (in certain contexts) behave like booleans at runtime (which is something that can trip people up from strict statically typed languages like Java).

Thus, using this theory knowledge we can determine logically that correct condition you are looking for is `if not (permission == "yes" or permission == "sure")`. As we want either of the the conditions `(permission == "yes")`, `(permission == "sure")` to be true, then we negate the value to maintain your if statement's structure.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `permission` will always either not equal `yes` or not equal `sure`,

```
if permission != "yes" or permission != "sure"
```

can't possibly be false.

Think about it this way: by [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), claiming that `permission != "yes" or permission != "sure"` is false is equivalent to claiming that `permission == "yes" and permission == "sure"`, which is impossible.

See also my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221998/using-or-operator-in-a-jquery-if-statement) for more details.