# Javascript !=="" not working right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    var search = $('#search').val();
    console.log(search);
    if (search.length !== 0 || search !== "") {
      $('.wrapper').css({
        "background-color": "#000",
        "opacity": 0.8
      });
      $('.post').remove();
    } else {
      location.reload(false);
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
</form>
```

but the problem is that whatever  put space at the beginning in the input element, the function is not working (it goes on to run `$('.wrapper').css({"background-color":"#000","opacity":0.8}); and $('.post').remove();` ).

Comment: check out `search.trim() !== ''`.

Comment: just a hint, you could replace the if condition with `if(search) {`

Comment: What does *"put space at the beginning in the input element"* mean? You mean *entering* a space (as value of the input element)?

Comment: um, if the length is zero, it will be equal to "". Also seems like you need to wait until the input is complete before you check.

Comment: `var search = $('#search').val().trim();` problem solved

Comment: You should use `&&` to combine `!==` tests, not `||`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/execute-block-if-a-variable-is-not-one-of-some-specific-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove spaces before and after the text:

```
var search = $('#search').val().trim();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    var search = $('#search').val().trim();

    if (search) {
      $('.wrapper').css({
        "background-color": "#000",
        "opacity": 0.8
      });
      $('.post').remove();
    } else {
      location.reload(false);
    };

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `search = search.trim();` before your conditional.

When you are adding a space to the input `search` is `' '` not `''` so a [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) is necessary.

Additionally, using:

```
if (search) {
    ....
}
```

instead of

```
if (search.length !== 0 || search !== '') {
    ...
}
```

Is a simpler check that will give you the same result in this case. Both `''` and `0` are ['falsey'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    var search = $('#search').val();
    search = search.trim(); //Try adding this line
    console.log(search);
    if (search.length !== 0 || search !== "") {
      $('.wrapper').css({
        "background-color": "#000",
        "opacity": 0.8
      });
      $('.post').remove();
    } else {
      location.reload(false);
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use ! or !! to check empty strings:

```
!"" // true
!!"" // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute the code if there is something in that field (aka. not `undefined`) and whatever is there, it is not blank (aka. not `''`). So, do a double check using the 'and' operator ( `&&` ) instead of 'or' ( `||` ). So try using:

```
if (search.length !== undefined && search !== '') {
 //execute code
}
```

In your js code snippet, that would look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    var search = $('#search').val();
    console.log(search);
    if (search !== undefined && search !== "") {
      $('.wrapper').css({
        "background-color": "#000",
        "opacity": 0.8
      });
      $('.post').remove();
    } else {
      location.reload(false);
    };
  });
});
```