# Why does this piece of my program always trigger?

Tags: python, if-statement

Here is a excerpt from my program:

```
weaponinput = input("Would you like a rifle, a pistol, or a shotgun?")
if weaponinput == " pistol":
    weapon = (int(pistol_1))
if weaponinput == " rifle":
    weapon = (int(rifle_1))
if weaponinput == " shotgun":
    weapon = (int(shotgun_1))
if weaponinput != (" shotgun") or (" rifle") or (" pistol") or (" sniper rifle"):
    print("In your futile attempt to turn",weaponinput,"into a weapon you accidentally blow your brains accross the ground.")
```

The `if` clause always triggers in line 8, no matter the value of `weaponinput`. Why does this happen? I am using python, and do not really understand many other languages

Comment: You can't speak to a computer in human sentences. `weaponinput != "shotgun" or "rifle"` is equivalent to `(weaponinput != "shotgun") or "rifle"`. `"rifle"` is a nonempty collection, and evaluates as true.

Comment: Are you actually typing a leading space when entering a value?  You're checking for one, for some reason...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true)

Comment: @jasonharper yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythonic would be:

```
if weaponinput not in (" shotgun", " rifle", " pistol", " sniper rifle"):
    print(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. This will help me in my other projects too.

Answer (score 4):

You have written the equivalent of

```
if (w != 1) or (2) or (3):
 print("something")
```

`(2)` is non-zero and therefore True.  In your code `("rifle")` is not None and therefore True.

The correct form is

```
if (w != 1) or (w!=2) or (w!=3):
    ...
```

Another way to do this might be

```
if weaponinput == "rifle:
    ...
elif weaponinput == "pistol": 
     ...
else:
    print("bad input message")
```

Yet another way:

```
WeaponCodes = {"pistol":int(pistol1), "rifle":int(rifle1), ... }
try:
   weapon = WeaponCodes[weaponinput]
except KeyError:
   print("bad input message")
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to change that line to the following:

```
if weaponinput != " shotgun" or weaponinput != " rifle" or weaponinput != " pistol" or weaponinput != " sniper rifle":
```

Comment: Or perhaps the more succinct `weaponinput not in [" shotgun", " rifle", " pistol", " sniper rifle"]`

Comment: Thtat's plausible.

Answer (score 0):

To check multiple conditions you have to compare your input variable with the required condition like:

`if var <conditional operator1> condition1 <logical operator> var <conditional operator2> condition2` and so on.

so in your case line number 8 must be:
`if weaponinput != " shotgun" or weaponinput != " rifle" or weaponinput != " pistol" or weaponinput != " sniper rifle":`

Answer (score 0):

Out of all operators, the logical operators(`or`, `and` and `not`) has the least priority ([Python Operator Precedence](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm)).

In Python the Boolean value of a non-empty string is always true.

So, the code you have written is equivalent to :-

```
weaponinput = input("Would you like a rifle, a pistol, or a shotgun?")
if weaponinput == " pistol":
    weapon = (int(pistol_1))
if weaponinput == " rifle":
    weapon = (int(rifle_1))
if weaponinput == " shotgun":
    weapon = (int(shotgun_1))
if weaponinput != (" shotgun") or True or True or True:
    print("In your futile attempt to turn",weaponinput,"into a weapon you accidentally blow your brains accross the ground.")
```

So, the condition in line 8 is always true irrespective of whether `weaponinput` is equal to `" shotgun`" or not(as `or` always evaluates to true if atleast one of its operand is true).