# Javascript promo code prompt - endless while loop

Tags: javascript

We're using a promo code to allow people access to a page. It doesn't have to be secure - just trying to give the customers a code prompt to make them feel special.

So I used this code... obviously I am doing something wrong because the browser keeps checking for the code even after they entered it (and eventually the page crashes). I tried break; at the end, but then prompt doesn't happen.

I would appreciate any help with this.

All I want to do is get rid of the endless loop here.

```js
var secret;

while (secret !== "1")
  if (secret !== "2")
    if (secret !== "3")
      if (secret !== "4") {
        secret = prompt("What is the secret password?");
      };
```

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Comment: The code will loop forever if you type `2`, `3`, or `4`, because the `if` statements prevent it from calling `prompt()` in those cases.

Comment: Why do you think you need those checks? Just check for the correct answer in the `while` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code goes into an infinite loop if the user types any of the numbers in the `if (secret != XX)` lines. This is because the `while` condition is met, but the `if` condition fails, so it skips over the `prompt()` function and repeats the `while`. Since this doesn't change `answer`, it keeps doing this over and over.

If you want to check for multiple possible answers, do them all in the `while` statement:

```js
var secret;
while (secret != "1" && secret != "2" && secret != "3" && secret != "4") {
  secret = prompt("What is the secret password");
}
```

Comment: Yo! This is what I was trying to do, but I used || instead of &&. Can you tell me why it it && and not || ? Thanks!

Comment: @Cliff Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/execute-block-if-a-variable-is-not-one-of-some-specific-values

Comment: Just think about it logically. If you type 3, then you have `true || true || false || true`. Since `||` is true if any of its operands is true, this is true, so it keeps looping.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is improper use of `while` mixed with `if`. Maybe you should consider an other approach:

```js
var askSecret = function askSecret() {
    var secret = prompt("What is the secret password?");
    if(secret !== "theSecret") { askSecret(); }
};
    
askSecret();
```

**Edit: multiple passwords/secrets**

In the previous example, the only valid secret/password is "theSecret". If you need to have more than one secret/password, you'll have to extend the conditional with an AND `&&` operator:

```js
var askSecret = function askSecret() {
    var secret = prompt("What is the secret password?");
    if(
        secret !== "theSecret"
    &&  secret !== "TheOtherSecret"
    &&  secret !== "TheThirdValidSecret"
    )
    {
        askSecret();
    }
};
    
askSecret();
```

Comment: thanks! I was trying to do this like the answer Barmar provided, but I derped. Please see my answer on Barmar's post. This also works but I was trying to allow more than one answer. I really appreciate your reply!

Comment: Change `if(secret !== "theSecret")` by `if(secret !== "myFirstSecret" && secret !== "mySecondSecret")`

Comment: thanks, nice work. I was using || instead of && in some of my attempts