# ENTER executes program instead of creating a newline

Tags: c, console

Following the book *The C Programming Language* by Kernighan and Ritchie, I am trying do the following exercise:

**Exercise 1-12** Write a program that prints its input one word per line.

This is my code:

```
main(){

int b;

while( (b=getchar()) != EOF){

    if(b != ' ' || b != '\t' || b != '\n')
        putchar(b);

    if(b == ' ' || b == '\t' || b == '\n')
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

My problem is that pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to get a newline executes the code in stead of just giving me a newline in the console.

Should not just an EOF do this? Otherwise, the program works just fine.

Edit: This is not, as far as I understand, a duplicate of [Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true%22Why%20non-equality%20check%20of%20one%20variable%20against%20many%20values%20always%20returns%20true?%22)
 Although I should have used "&&" and not "||", the problem remains. When I press ENTER in the console, the program is executed in stead of giving me a newline. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Logic problem, the first `if` should be `if(b != ' ' && b != '\t' && b != '\n')`

Comment: Or, even better, skip the first `if` altogether, and instead attach an `else` block to the second.