# Conditions in Python

Tags: python

I'm having difficulty understand this logic:

```
>>> text = 'ay_118724981.jpg'
>>> 'jpg' in text
True
>>> 'png' in text
False
>>> if 'png' not in text or 'jpg' not in text or 'jpeg' not in text:
...     print('True')
... else:
...     print('False')
... 
True
>>>
```

I'm confused 'coz the if statement should result in **False** since 'jpg' **is** in the text. It should give me True **only** when none of them is in the text. Correct ?

Comment: In that case you should use`and`. Such that from the moment one of the conditions is `False`, it fails.

Comment: not all the strings are in the text: True. Try avoid the negations and check out De Morgan's law

Comment: `'png' not in text` is `True`, everything after that is not even evaluated. `a or b` is true if `a` is true or b is true or both are true.

Comment: python conditional statement are like plain english. convert your statement to english equivalent and ask yourself "why the result from the program is different than your expectation" and you'll get your answer

Comment: I don't think so mate. Here I'm checking whether at least one is True. I'm not checking if all strings are true or false.

Comment: Great, you understood it.

Comment: If `a or b` is true, return `True`.  Here `a` is true, so `or` shortcuts after the first true statement, e.g. `'png' not in text`.  You want to use `and`.

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri   I did that lol. 'jpg' is clearly there and I proved it in the line above it.

Comment: At this point I begin to question whether you understand the meaning of the word "or" in the english language.

Comment: @MarkAlexa Need to work on your boolean math a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It parses out as `('png' not in text) or ('jpg' not in text) or ('jpeg' not in text)`.

One of those conditions is true ('png' is not in `text`), so it evaluates as true. You can get the behavior you are expecting with an `and`

Comment: Yes ... it works the way all of you say. I guess I had it upside-down.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused [because] the if statement should result in False since 'jpg' is in the text. It should give me True only when none of them is in the text. Correct ?

No, the `or` operator is `True` if *one or both* of the operands is `True`. So from the moment, `'jpg'` is not in the text, or `'png'` is not in the text, or `jpeg` is not in the text, the test *succeeds*.

What you want here is the `and` operator. `x and y` is True, only when *both* operands (`x` and `y`) are not in the text. So we can use:

```
if 'png' not in text and 'jpg' not in text and 'jpeg' not in text:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Since it can be confusing, and since this is a long expression, we can also use the `all(..)` builtin function here:

```
if all(part not in s for part in ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

So only if *all* these `part`s are not in `s`, then the condition succeeds.

Comment: I thought I understand simple logic such as this but apparently I need review it. Embarrassing, really.