# C++ Loops forever

Tags: c++, loops, input

I wrote the following loop as a part of a program for my CS homework, however regardless of the input, the program keeps looping at this exact point. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char choice;
do
{
  cout << "Type 'c' for characters or type 'n' for numbers: ";
  cin >> choice;
}while (choice != 'c' || choice != 'n');
```

Comment: Review the meaning of `||`.  Try saying the expression out loud.

Comment: Your condition always evaluates to `true` do to use of `||` operator.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: You cannot be 'c' and 'n' at same time, so it loops forever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `do`-`while` statement loops as long as the `while` expression is `true`.

Your `while` expression is

```
choice != 'c' || choice != 'n'
```

In common English, that expression means

> `choice` is not `'c'` **OR** `choice` is not `'n'`

That statement, logically, is **always true**.  `choice` is **always** not one of those things.

In both English and C++, you would want to use `and`/`&&` in that expression.

Comment: Oh I thought or was the way to achieve that effect. It makes more sense when you put it like that, thanks!