# OR logical operator in bash test

Tags: bash, logical-operators

The test seems not to work properly. Why ? 
I need a script which takes the first argument, checks which letter it is and does the job. If the letter is a,b,c or d it exits, otherwise rights something.

```
letter=$1                                                                                                                                             


[[ $letter != a || $letter != b || $letter != c || $letter != d ]] && echo exiting && exit 1                                                          


if [[ $letter == a ]]                                                                                                                                 
then                                                                                                                                                  
echo correct                                                                                                                                      
fi
```

Comment: Context for the duplicate flag: [Canonical, language-agnostic question for `if(var != x || var != y)`?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/canonical-language-agnostic-question-for-ifvar-x-var-y)

Comment: ...note the [answer by @triplee on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48144901/14122), specifically going into bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a simpler example: `[[ $letter != a || $letter != b ]]` No matter what `letter` is, one of those two tests is true. If you pick `a`, then `$letter != b`. If you pick `b`, then `$letter != a`. If you pick any other character, *both* are true.

You want `&&` instead:

```
[[ $letter != a && $letter != b && $letter != c && $letter !=d ]] && { echo exiting; exit 1; }.
```

Or use `=`/`==` and use `||` *after* the test.

```
[[ $letter = a || $letter = b || $letter = c || $letter = d ]] || { echo exiting; exit 1; }
```

(In both cases, prefer an explicit `if` statement rather than using `&&` or `||`:

```
if [[ $letter != a && $letter != b ... ]]; then
    echo exiting >&2  # use standard error, not standard output
    exit 1
fi

if ! [[ $letter = a || $letter = b ... ]]; then
     echo exiting >&2  # use standard error, not standard output
     exit 1
fi
```

)

Much simpler, though, is to use a `case` statement:

```
case $letter in
    a|b|c|d) : ;;  # do nothing
    *) echo exiting
       exit 1
       ;;
esac
```

Comment: Probably ought to do the `&& { echo exiting; exit 1; }` thing even in the first code sample -- that way we still reach the `exit` even if the `echo` fails.

Comment: Thank you chepner for the answer and Charles Duffy for the links, it was very helpful.