# why do I get ZeroDivisionError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I am trying to write python program that reads a .csv file. I have in the input file 4 columns/fields and I want to only have 2 in the output with one being a new one.

This is the input I am using:

```
MID,REP,NAME,NEPTUN
0,,"people's front of judea",GM6MRT
17,,Steve Jobs,NC3J0K
,0,Brian,RQQCFE
19,9,Pontius Pilate,BQ6IAJ
1,,N. Jesus,QDMXVF
18,,Bill Gates,D1CXLO
0,,"knights who say NI",CZN5JA
 ,1,"Robin, the brave",BWQ5AU
17,19,"Gelehed, the pure",BY9B8G
```

then the output should be something like this(not full output):

```
NEPTUN,GROWTH
BQ6IAJ,-0.5263157894736842
BWQ5AU,inf
BY9B8G,0.11764705882352941
RQQCFE,0
```

The new field called `GROWTH` is calculated by (REP-MID)/MID.

So, I am using two lists to do that:

```
import csv

L = []
s =[]
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as R:
    reader = csv.DictReader(R)
    for x in reader:
        if  x['MID'] != '' or '0' and x['REP'] == '':
            Growth = -float(x['MID'])/float(x['MID'])
            L.append(x)
            s.append(Growth)
        elif  x['MID'] != '' or '0':
            Growth = (float(x['REP']))-float(x['MID'])/float(x['MID'])
            L.append(x)
            s.append(Growth)
        elif x['MID'] and x['REP'] == '' or '0' :
            Growth = 0
            L.append(x)
            s.append(Growth) 
        else:
            Growth = float("inf")
            L.append(x)
            s.append(Growth) 
    for i in range(len(s)):
        L[i]['GROWTH'] = i
R.close()
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as output:
    fields = ['NEPTUN', 'GROWTH']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fields, extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(L)
output.close()
```

Now, I am not even sure if the code is correct or does what I aim it for, because I am stuck at a `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero` at the first `if`condition and I tried many ways to avoid it but I get the same error.

I thought the problem is that when there are no values for `MID` field, I think the dictionary gives it ``` `` ``` value and that can't be transformed to `0` by `float()`. But it seems that is not the problem, but honestly I have no idea now, so that is  why I am asking here.

the full error:

```
Growth = -float(x['MID'])/float(x['MID'])

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Any hints about this are greatly valued.

Comment: What is `if  x['MID'] != '' or '' and x['REP'] == '':` supposed to mean?

Comment: it looks like `x['MID']` is 0

Comment: @WhatsThePoint ,I edited it, it was a typo

Comment: @Kadir.J `or '0'` doesn't actually mean anything, it just returns true as a string is always true, so it will always fall into your if statement

Comment: @barmar,  `x['REP'] == ''` is for when REP is equal to nothing, because otherwise it gives me can not transform a float from a string error

Comment: Should be `if  x['MID'] != '' and x['MID'] != '0' and x['REP'] == '':`

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/execute-block-if-a-variable-is-not-one-of-some-specific-values

Comment: @Barmar yes that fixed it, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if x['MID'] != '' or '0' and x['REP'] == ''
```

This does not mean what you think it means. It is interpreted as

```
if ((x['Mid'] != '') or ('0')) and (x['REP'] == '')
```

which shortens to

```
if True and x['REP'] == ''
```

which in turn becomes

```
if x['REP'] == ''
```

---

What you mean is

```
if x['Mid'] not in ('', '0') and (x['REP'] == ''):
```

You need to do the same for your other `if` statements