# why does if (a == b || c) && (d != 0) {operation 1} run by default but (a == e || f ) && (d!= 0) {op2} get ignored?

Tags: c++

So, I'm running some code and I got it to work, but I have two if else statements.

Let's say

```
if (( a == 'b'||'c') && (d!=0)) {
    // do operation1;
} else if (( a == 'e'||'f') && (d!=0)) {
    // do operation2; 
}
```

operation 1 runs by default when my code was structured that way. What do I mean by default? If I tried typing the input 'e' or 'f' it would do operation 1 as if I had typed in 'b' or 'c'
But then I tried something different.

```
if ((a == 'b') || (a == 'c') && (b != 0)) {
    // do operation 1;
} else if ((a == 'e') || (a == 'f') && (b!= 0)) {
    // do operation 2;
}
```

See NOW operation 1 and 2 are working as intended.

Why does this happen?

Comment: For language behavior questions you really should tag the language you're using. A lot of programming languages have `if-else` and many use at least something similar to the syntax you are showing.

Comment: My bad. The language is c++

Comment: BTW, this is a FAQ -- we have a language-agnostic meta-answer.

Comment: ...hmm, actually, I was thinking of [Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true), but that's the **inequality** version. (See also [Canonical, language-agnostic question for if(var != “x” || var != “y” …)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/canonical-language-agnostic-question-for-ifvar-x-var-y) on [meta])

Comment: [How to test multiple variables against a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value) is a Python-flavored duplicate. Still looking for a C/C++ one.

Comment: Your code is non-compilable. In C++ `if` requires a pair of `()` around its condition. Post something more meaningful.

Comment: What are example values of the variables `a` and `d`?

Answer (score 1):

```
a == 'e'||'f'
```

isn't doing what you think it's doing. 'f' as a boolean because its larger than the value 0, will always be considered true. Try the following.

```
a == 'e' || a == 'f'
```

The large difference between the two sets of code you have there, aren't the (brackets), it's the useage of '=='.