# Insert a Variable of String into an array

Tags: php, email, sendinblue

I'm using a Sendinblue SMTP into my PHP project and I want to send transactionals emails to a dynamic list of emails, the problem is that I have a syntax error when I'm using a variable instead a string. For example, this code works great:

```
    include 'Mailin.php';
    $mailin = new Mailin('senders@sender.com', 'key');
    $mailin->
    addTo(
        array(
                 'email1@email.com' => '', 'email2@email.com' => '', 'email3@email.com' => ''
            )
    )->

    setFrom('sender@sender.com', 'Test')->
    setReplyTo('sender@sender.com', 'Test')->
    setSubject('Example')->
    setText('Test')->
    setHtml($htmlContent);
    $res = $mailin->send();
    print_r($res);
```

But if I use a variable instead the Strings in "addTo Array" it shows syntax error, for example:

```
    $customers = '';
    foreach ($clientes as $customer) {

        for ($i=1; $i < 41; $i++) { 

            if ($customer['email'.$i]  != "" or $customer['email'.$i] != NULL) {

                $customers .= "'".$customer['email'.$i]. "' => '', " ; //for each customer's email add the email in " 'email@email.com' => '', " format
            }
        }
    }

    $customers = substr($customers, 0, -2); //removes last space and comma of the String

    include 'Mailin.php';
    $mailin = new Mailin('senders@sender.com', 'key');
    $mailin->
    addTo(
        array(
                 $customers
            )
    )->

    setFrom('sender@sender.com', 'Test')->
    setReplyTo('sender@sender.com', 'Test')->
    setSubject('Example')->
    setText('Test')->
    setHtml($htmlContent);
    $res = $mailin->send();
    print_r($res);
```

If I use the Print_r($customers) function it shows the exact string that I used in my first example, even if I use the code:

```
    $text = "'email1@email.com' => '', 'email2@email.com' => '', 'email3@email.com' => ''";

    if ($customers == $text) {
        print_r("Yes");
    }else{
        print_r("No");
    }
```

The result is "Yes", but when I use the variable in

```
    addTo(
        array(
                 $customers
            )
    )->
```

shows an error, but if I use the string directly the email is sent

```
    addTo(
        array(
                 'email1@email.com' => '', 'email2@email.com' => '', 'email3@email.com' => ''
            )
    )->
```

And I don't know why it shows error if the $customers variable has the string that is needed.

Do you know how to use the variable with the emails that I need to send?

Comment: Why not just build out a `$customer` array instead of a string?

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Also you can consider creating an array, rather than providing emails as a string

Comment: Because Sendinblue only acept this format

Comment: The error is 

    {"result":false,"code":501,"message":"Unable to send email. Exception message was: Error: Bad recipient address syntax.","data":{"message-id":""}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't build an array by concatenating strings with `=>` in them. To create an element in an associative array, just assign to that array index.

```
$customers = [];
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    for ($i = 1; $i < 41; $i++) {
        if (!empty($customer["email" . $i])) {
            $customers[$customer["email" . $i]] = "";
        }
    }
}
include 'Mailin.php';
$mailin = new Mailin('senders@sender.com', 'key');
$mailin->
addTo($customers)->
...
```

Also, see [Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/execute-block-if-a-variable-is-not-one-of-some-specific-values) for why you should have used `&&` rather than `||` when you were skipping empty emails (which I've simplified by using `!empty()`).