# some() function is not working with && operator

Tags: javascript, operators

I´m triying to use the some() function with && operator, but always return false, even if both conditions are inside in the array.
For example:

```
  if (acciones.some(a => a.accionID == 7 && a.accionID == 8)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: `accionID` can't be `7` and `8` at same time

Comment: Did you mean to use `||` for "or"?

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true

Comment: Btw, don't do `if (…) return true else return false;`, just `return …`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're checking one specific `accionID` on each call to the `some` callback. That one `accionID` **cannot** be both `== 7` and `== 8` at the same time. Any given `accionID` will be `7` **or** `8`.

If you want to see if all of the `acciones` have `accionID` of `7` or `8`, use `every` with `||`:

```
if (acciones.every(a => a.accionID == 7 || a.accionID == 8)) {
// ----------^--------------------------^
```

If you want to see if **any** of the `acciones` has an `accionID` of `7` or `8`, use `some` with `||`:

```
if (acciones.some(a => a.accionID == 7 || a.accionID == 8)) {
// ----------^-------------------------^
```

If `acciones` has at least one entry in it where `accionID` is (say) `6`, the `every` check will be false, and the `some` check will be true.

---

Since `some` and `every` *already* return a boolean, there's no need for:

```
if (acciones.every(a => a.accionID == 7 || a.accionID == 8)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Just use

```
return acciones.every(a => a.accionID == 7 || a.accionID == 8);
```

In general, if you find yourself writing:

```
if (x) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

then:

1. If `x` is already a boolean, you can do just

   ```
   return x;
   ```
2. If `x` is not necessarily boolean (and it matters that you return a boolean, specifically), you can use the `!!` idiom to make it a boolean:

   ```
   return !!x;
   ```

Similarly, if you find yourself writing:

```
if (x) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

you can always write that as

```
return !x;
```

instead.