# Multiple conditions in c#

Tags: c#

```
while (playerMove != "SCISSORS" || playerMove != "PAPER" && playerMove != "ROCK" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(playerMove))
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid command!");
     playerChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();
     continue;
   }
```

Can someone explain to a beginner programmer why this code doesn't work.
The way I read this code myself is:
While playerMove isn't "SCISSORS" or "PAPER" and isn't "ROCK" or Empty, do this...

How do I make this work?

Comment: check [this](https://kodify.net/csharp/if-else/short-circuit-if/) article. it may help you

Comment: In your case I'd recommend using an Enum to define Rock, Paper & Scissors. Then using a switch-case to determine what the user selected and what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does non-equality check of one variable against many values always return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-does-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-return-tr)

Answer (score 4):

If you enter "PAPER", then `playerMove != "SCISSORS"` is true, so your while-condition is true, because only one part of a logical OR has to be true.

You want *all* of the `!="XYZ"` to be true, OR the string to be empty:

```
while((playerMove != "SCISSORS" && playerMove != "PAPER" && playerMove != "ROCK") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(playerMove))
```

That said, there are probably easier ways to check this.

You could define a list of acceptable strings, for instance, and check against that:

```
using System.Linq;
...
var acceptedString = new List<string> {"ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"};
...
while (!acceptedStrings.Contains(playermove)
{
   // error message
}
```

Actually checking for an empty string is useless, since an empty string never has an accepted value.

Another option, as mentioned in a comment, is to extract your condition to a method. This is almost always a good idea for complicated conditions:

```
while (!IsValid(playermove)){...}
...
private static bool IsValid(string move)
{
   return move == "ROCK"
       || move == "PAPER"
       || move == "SCISSORS";
}
```

Alternatively you can rewrite that to

```
while (!IsValid(playermove)){...}
...
private static bool IsValid(string move) =>
    move == "ROCK" || move == "PAPER" || move == "SCISSORS";
```

Comment: Could you maybe give some advice, regarding the best practice for checking something like this. I'm soaking up any information you can throw at me. Any advice would help.

Comment: I feel like defining a list for only 3 choices decreases readability. I'd rather extract the logic in a method: `private bool IsValidChoice(string choice) => choice == "SCISSORS" || choice == "PAPER" || choice == "ROCK";` Then loop on it: `while (!IsValidChoice(playerMove))`

Comment: But our two solutions converge on one point: mixing multiple negative statements is hard to read. It's better to make positive statements, then negate them as a whole

Comment: @KevinGosse there are many different options, of course. And I agree that in general you should use a method for a complicated condition - I'll add that option as well :)

Comment: Thank you both for the information, looking into both answers right now, since you both agree a method is the best thing to do. i'll start with this.

Answer (score 0):

I feel so dumb right now, i only just noticed i broke my head over this code for no reason.
I noticed in the loop i asked to set a new value to "playerChoice", instead of playerMove. hence why it didnt run the way i wanted it to.

```
while ((playerMove != "SCISSORS" && playerMove != "PAPER" && playerMove != "ROCK") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(playerMove))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid command!");
                    playerMove = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();
                    continue;
                }
```

Including answer into the conditions aswell.