# My while loop only works the second time instead of first

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `while` loop and if you answer the question wrong, it repeats the question, but when I get it right first time it ask again and it works the second time. code:

```
def signup():
    signup=input("Enter a username: ")
    signup2=input("Enter a password: ")

def login():
    login=input("Enter your username: ")
    login2=input("Enter your password: ")

option=input("Would you like to login or signup?: ")

while option != "signup" or option != "login":

    option=input("Would you like to login or signup?: ")

    if option == "signup":
        signup()
    elif option == "login":
        login()
```

and the response is:

```
Would you like to login or signup?: signup
Would you like to login or signup?: signup
Enter a username:
```

Comment: You ask for input twice. Once before the loop, and again inside the loop.

Comment: If `option == "signup"`, it is guaranteed that `option != "login"`. Use `and`, or use `not (option == "signup" and option == "login"). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws.

Comment: This is a good case to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is incorrect. If `option` does equal one or the other, the other comparison is *guaranteed* to be true. You want to use `and`, not `or`

```
while option != "signup" and option != "login":
```

or by [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

```
while not (option == "signup" or option == "login"):
```

The best solution, though, is to use an "infinite" loop with an explicit `break` statement, so that you only need to write the call to `input` once.

```
while True:

    option=input("Would you like to login or signup?: ")

    if option == "signup" or option == "login":
        break


if option == "signup":
    signup()
elif option == "login":
    login()
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, since you also place the `option=input("Would you like to login or signup?: ")` outside the loop first. To make this kind of loop, it's better to make an infinite loop and to break on a condition:

```
while True:

    option=input("Would you like to login or signup?: ")

    if option == "signup":
        signup()
        break
    elif option == "login":
        login()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for input a second time inside the loop. You should only do that if the input wasn't one of the valid choices.

You should use `and` rather than `or` to test the input. See [Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/execute-block-if-a-variable-is-not-one-of-some-specific-values)

Finally, you should process the input *after* the loop, since that's when it will contain a valid choice.

```
option=input("Would you like to login or signup?: ")
while option != "signup" and option != "login":
    option=input("Would you like to login or signup?: ")

if option == "signup":
    signup()
elif option == "login":
    login()
```