# I am trying to create a JavaScript program that prompts the user "enter yes or no to exit"

Tags: javascript, loops

```
let q;

while ((q !== "yes")||(q !== "no")) {
  q = prompt("yes or no?");
}
```

I've tried this and I couldn't understand why it wouldn't work since this:

```
while (q !== "yes") {
  q = prompt("yes or no?");
}
```

works.

Comment: `(q !== "yes")||(q !== "no")` will always evaluate to true since `q` can only be one thing. It'll either not be yes or not be no, or possibly not be either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
(q !== "yes")||(q !== "no")
```

will always be be truthy, because `q` can't be both `yes` and `no` at the same time. If either condition is fulfilled, that `while` will be truthy, and the loop will continue.

Use `&&` instead:

```
(q !== "yes") && (q !== "no")
```

Or, even more readably, use `.includes`:

```
while (!['yes', 'no'].includes(q)) {
```

```js
let q;
while (!['yes', 'no'].includes(q)) {
  q = prompt("yes or no?");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uh, it seems that you used

```
while ((q !== "yes")||(q !== "no"))
```

This will always translate to `true` since q cannot be both "yes" and "no", it will always evaluate to true. The condition should be should be

```
while ((q !== "yes") && (q !== "no"))
```