# Why isn't this repeating three times?

Tags: java

I don't know this keeps repeating "The last person who went lost". I want to try making this repeat the game 3 times so players can plat it 3 times but it won't repeat. Also, when I try my if(enter!=1||enter!=2) stuff keeps repeating its self even when I type in 1 or 2 can someone help me please?

```
for(d=0;d<3;d++)
    {
    while(sticks>0) {
    System.out.println("Player 1 how many sticks would you like to take? 1 or 2?");
    int  enter = numScan.nextInt();//this tells us how many they're going to take
    sticks=sticks-enter;
    if(enter!=1||enter!=2)//this makes it so people who don't enter a right number are forced to replay the program and suffer
    {
        System.out.println("please run this program again");

    }
    System.out.println("There are "+sticks+" sticks left!");
    System.out.println("Player 2 how many sticks would you like to take? 1 or 2");
    System.out.println("Ther are "+sticks+" sticks left!");
    int enter2=numScan.nextInt();//this is the second enter 
     sticks=sticks-enter2;//this will tell us how many sticks are left 
    if(enter2!=1 || enter2!=2)//this makes it so people who don't enter a right number are forced to replay the program and suffer
    {
        System.out.println("please run this program again");

    }

    System.out.println("Player 1 how many sticks would you like to take? 1 or 2?");
    int enter3=numScan.nextInt();//this is the second enter 
    sticks=sticks-enter3;//this will tell us how many sticks are left 
    System.out.println("There are "+sticks+" sticks left!");
    }
    if(sticks<0||sticks==0)
    {
        System.out.println("The last player who went lost!");
    }
}





}
```

}

Comment: You never reset the value of `sticks`. So once it is zero (or less), it is **always** zero (or less). Also every number will match `enter!=1||enter!=2` because one is not two **and** two is not one.

Comment: Can you show any value for which `if(enter2!=1 || enter2!=2)` would be false? Please "calculate" it on paper. Related: [Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26337003)

Comment: How do I reset the value of sticks?

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401251/why-isnt-this-repeating-three-times#comment104991611_59401251), the reason why you keep getting the same message after the first game finishes is the fact that the value of `sticks` is not being reset at the end (or the start) of the game.

In order to solve your problem I would suggest setting the value of `sticks` before the round of the game starts, like this:

```
for(d=0;d<3;d++)
    sticks = 20; //the value with which you initialize the game
    {
    while(sticks>0) {
    System.out.println("Player 1 how many sticks would you like to take? 1 or 2?");
    int  enter = numScan.nextInt();//this tells us how many they're going to take
```

There might be other solutions. But in general, you should set the "rules" of the game or "initialize the variables" in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(enter!=1||enter!=2)
```

change to

```
if(enter!=1 && enter!=2) //not easy to understand and requires thinking

if(sticks<0||sticks==0) //equivalent to if(sticks<=0)
```