# Why does the 'and' work in this while loop and 'or' doesn't?

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop

I built a guessing game with some help. Why does the while loop terminate when only one condition is false if it's using `and`. Wouldn't `or` fit better here?

```
secret_word = "pirate"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False


while guess != secret_word and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter a guess:" )
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True
        print("Out of guesses")
```

How does this work?

```
while guess != secret_word and not(out_of_guesses):
```

Comment: Does `while not (guess == secret_word or out_of_guesses):` make more sense? This is an application of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: _How does this work?_ Which part are you stuck on? As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in `while` specifies when the loop should keep running. `and` means that both conditions have to be true for the expression to be true. So if either of the conditions is false, the `and` expression is false, and the loop stops.

If you change it to `or`, the expression is true if either condition is true. So you'll keep looping as long as the user doesn't guess the word, even if they've run out of guesses.

Comment: Got it! `and` returns true if both are true. `and` returns false if one is false. I thought the `and` meant both had to be false to return false. Can you help me understand `not()` more better? Thanks!

Comment: `not` returns true if the operand is false, and returns false if the operand is true.

Comment: if  `not` returns true if it is false, then is the while condition is false since `out_of_guesses = False` and `not(out_of_guesses)` Wouldn't that make `out_of_guesses` true?

Comment: It doesn't change `out_of_guesses`, it just returns the opposite of it.

Comment: When `out_of_guesses` is False, `not out_of_guesses` is True.

Comment: So wouldn't the program read `not(out_of_guesses)` as true and terminate it?

Comment: No. The condition is for when to continue looping, not when to stop.

Comment: If you said "while the sun is out I'll stay at the beach", you wouldn't leave the beach when the sun comes out, would you?

Comment: I think I got it. `not` looks for a false value, and until it is changed it condition is true. Have to plant it in my head, the guy I'm learning from taught me in a weird way.

Comment: Similarly: "while it's not raining I'll stay at the beach"

Comment: @Na-s "not looks for a false value" I think this is the wrong way to think about it. `not`, `or` and `and` are operators that return a value. These operators act on boolean values as inputs. This is exaclty the same as how `-`, `+`, and `*` produce numbers as output when given numbers as input. The result of `not x` is to reverse the boolean value of `x`. So if `x` is `True`, then `not x` is `False` and vice versa. There are a lot of resources online that explain how this works, so don't rely only on your teacher.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I got it now. `True and True` returns `True`. `not` switches the boolean to true, which runs the loop. `or` wouldn't work because `True or False` just returns `True` and it would keep running. Thanks for your help, I'm glad I got it.

Comment: @Na-s See also this question, which addresses a common error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/execute-block-if-a-variable-is-not-one-of-some-specific-values

Comment: @Na-s Exactly! Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

We can use some variables to help describe the conditions:

```
guessed_wrong = guess != secret_word
has_more_guesses = not out_of_guesses
while guessed_wrong and has_more_guesses:
    # ...
    guessed_wrong = guess != secret_word
    has_more_guesses = not out_of_guesses
```

Now the wording should make it more clear why the loop should continue and why `or` is incorrect to use here.