# Function called from if statement not working

Tags: python, function, tkinter, while-loop

I'm trying to call different functions based on the user input in the Tkinter window for the `user_input3` variable.

Basically, in case the user inputs c, il calls `def creation()`, m calls `def lastmodified()` and a calls `def lastaccessed()`

Problem is, it goes in an infinite loop asking for the user_input3 string in the while loop.

**How can I resolve this?**

Also, for some reason I can't get to use match(input): etc. AKA *match pattern* in my code, this is why I'm using the method in my code...

*Thanks for the help and here is my code:*

```
def creation():
    lst.sort(key=os.path.getctime)
    num = 1
    for line in lst:
        dst = newpath + name + str(num) + suffix
        rename(line, dst)
        num += 1

def lastmodified():
    lst.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
    num = 1
    for line in lst:
        dst = newpath + name + str(num) + suffix
        rename(line, dst)
        num += 1

def lastaccessed():
    lst.sort(key=os.path.getatime())
    num = 1
    for line in lst:
        dst = newpath + name + str(num) + suffix
        rename(line, dst)
        num += 1

root = tkinter.Tk()

filez = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Select files to rename (must be all of the same type!)')

lst = list(filez)

suffix = pathlib.Path(lst[1]).suffix

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("400x240")

ROOT = tkinter.Tk()
ROOT.withdraw()

USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="File Names", prompt="Name your files:")

username = getpass.getuser()

name = USER_INP

USER_INP2 = simpledialog.askstring(title="Folder Name", prompt="Name your folder:")

foldername = USER_INP2

newpath = r'/Users/' + username + '/Desktop/' + foldername + '/'
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

user_input3 = simpledialog.askstring(title="Mode",
                                         prompt="Write: c to order by creation, m by last modified, a by last accessed")

while user_input3 != 'c' or user_input3 != 'm' or user_input3 != 'a':
    user_input3 = simpledialog.askstring(title="Mode",
                                         prompt="Write: c to order by creation, m by last modified, a by last accessed")

if user_input3 == 'c':
    creation()
elif user_input3 == 'm':
    lastmodified()
elif user_input3 == 'a':
    lastaccessed()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michy/PycharmProjects/Order_My_Files/Order_My_Files.py", line 110, in <module>
    lastaccessed()
  File "/Users/michy/PycharmProjects/Order_My_Files/Order_My_Files.py", line 47, in lastaccessed
    lst.sort(key=os.path.getatime())
TypeError: getatime() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
```

Comment: Your `while` loop is wrong, it should use `and`, not `or`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/execute-block-if-a-variable-is-not-one-of-some-specific-values

Comment: @Barmar But I want it to exit the loop when one of the strings is achieved. Shouldn’t it be or?

Comment: You want to break out if it's `c`, or `m`, or `a`, but you want to loop if it's not `c`, and not `m`, and not `a`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @RandomDavis Exactly!

Comment: @MichelangeloAmorusoManzari right, so I deliberately used the words "or" and "and" to demonstrate how your logic is backwards.

Comment: If the value is `c` then `input3 != 'm'` is true, so the loop continues.

Comment: @RandomDavis OHHH, wait, I'll run it and tell you have it goes, thanks in advance and maybe I completely got the logic wrong, probably.

Comment: It would be simpler if you wrote `while input3 not in ('c', 'm', 'a'):`

Comment: This is one of De Morgan's Laws: not (P or Q) <=> (not P) and (not Q)

Comment: Let me ask one last question before you close it guys. @RandomDavis why do I get the error I edited at the end of the question if I try the "last access" type?

Comment: @MichelangeloAmorusoManzari because you wrote `key=os.path.getatime()` instead of `key=os.path.getatime`.

Comment: @RandomDavis thank you so much! Have a lovely day!