# Using find to find files WITH a certain pattern and not other pattern

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-findutils

I want to use `find` to find files with `_101_` in the name and not `.jpg` or `.wsq` extensions, but I cannot get this to work.

I tried things like this:

```
find . -type f  -name '*_101_*' -o -not -name *.jpg -o -name *.wsq
```

but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The way logical NOT combines with OR and AND can be unintuitive; I recommend learning about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (and see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt does "matches `_101_`, or does not end in `.jpg`, or does not end in `.wsq`". That'll match every single file, based on the two extensions alone, as a file can only have one.

You have to group differently:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*_101_*' -not -name '*.jpg' -not -name '*.wsq'
```

This applies all rules (logical AND is implied).

You also should quote the parameters to `-name`, or they might be expanded by the shell instead of `find`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parenthesis (or @Benjamin's solution)

otherwise `a or not b or c` is evaluated as `(a or not b) or c`.

And you need `and` instead of `or` to filter only files that satisfy both conditions (pass both tests). `a and not (b or c)`

```sh
find -name '*_101_*' -not \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.wsq' \)
```