# Conditional Exclusion with Strings

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm still very much an beginner with Python (Spyder), more of my experience is with SQL and SAS. Therefore I'm unsure how to apply a wildcard to a string for conditional exclusion. For example, I have a list shown below and I want to exclude anything that ends with \New or \xNew.

Current List:

| Model |
| --- |
| Chrysler |
| Chrysler\New |
| Chrysler\xNew |
| Ford\New |
| Ford\xNew |
| Ford |

Code that I tried to use:

```
for car in cars:
   if '*\New' not in Model or '*\xNew' not in Model:
```

Comment: What is `cars` and why aren't you using the `car` iteration variable?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match

Comment: `substring in string` doesn't need a wildcard in python. Using `model` instead of `car` in your iteration, and the difference of `or not` vs `and not` are what's messing you up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `*`. And you need to use `and` to combine the conditions, not `or` (see [Why does non-equality check of one variable against many values always return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true))

Backslash is the escape character in Python strings. If you want to match it literally, either double it or use a raw string.

```
for model in cars:
    if r'\New' not in model and r'\xNew' not in model:
        // do something
```

If you want a list of these models, you can use a list comprehension with the above condition:

```
new_cars = [model for model in cars if r'\New' not in model and r'\xNew' not in model]
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm used to % as a wildcard in SQL and I tried researching wildcard characters for Python, but was having no success. Your solution solved my problem.

Comment: You don't need a wildcard if you just want to match a substring. This is like `IF LOCATE(model, 'car')` from SQL -- you don't need a wildcard there, either.\

Comment: `model.endswith()` might be more applicable here.