# How can I return True "1,2,3,4"?

Tags: python

The problem is complete the solution, a function that verifies that the string s is 4 or 6 long and consists only of numbers. For example, if s is "a234", return False, and if s is "1234", return True.

I didn't know why return False when s is "1234" in line 2 to line 3??

How can i fix it?

The len(s) is 4!

```
if len(s) != 4 or len(s) !=6:
        return False
```

Comment: your code returns false if either len is different than 4 or len is different than 6. Think about it, it triggers always for any length.

Comment: ***Everything*** is '!= 4 or != 6', including 4 and 6 and 12837198273.

Comment: [Why does non-equality check of one variable against many values always return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26337003/3890632)

Comment: The length is 4, but the length is not 6. You want `and`, not `or`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
len(s) in (4,6) and s.isdigit()
```

example:

- `s = '1234'`: `True`
- `s = 'a234'`: `False`
- `s = '12345'`: `False`

Your attempt failed because `len(s) != 4 or len(s) !=6` is always True (to be False you would need a number that is both 4 and 6 at the same time: impossible)