# Why does this Date Comparison in my If-Statement go wrong?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, date, if-statement

I want to check, if the date of a "wh"-Object is NOT a Saturday or Sunday.

```
this.state.workingHours.map((wh) => {
      if (wh.date.getDay() !== 6 || wh.date.getDay() !== 0) {
        console.log(
          "goes in",
          this.context.dateService.format(wh.date, "EEEE")
        );
      }
    });
```

In my console output, it looks like:
goes in Wednesday
goes in Thursday
goes in Friday
goes in Saturday
goes in Sunday
goes in Monday
...

Why does the date comparison not work?

Comment: Because your if statement is always true. Change `||` to `&&`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does non-equality check of one variable against many values always return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-does-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-return-tr)