# Exception occurred, segmentation fault while using free() in c;

Tags: c, exception, data-structures, malloc, free

My code somehow ran but it was not giving an expected outcome, so to understand it I started debugging and it shows an exception occurred, a segmentation fault at the line where I'm using `free()`.
Here's my code :

```
struct stack
{
    char ch;
    struct stack *prev;
} *top = NULL;

typedef struct stack st;

char pop();
void push(char c);
int evaluate(char arr[100]);

int main()
{
    char arr[100];
    printf("Enter the string to check format of string in wcwR");
    gets(arr);
    if (evaluate(arr) == 1)
    {
        printf("Entered string is in correct format");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Entered string is in wrong format");
    }
}

int evaluate(char arr[100])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; arr[i] != 'c' && arr[i] != 'C'; i++)
    {
        push(arr[i]);
    }
    i++;
    int j = i;
    int flag = 0;
    while (arr[j] != '\0')
    {
        if (arr[j] != pop())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

void push(char c)
{
    st *p;
    p = (struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    p->ch = c;
    p->prev = top;
    top = p;
}

char pop()
{
    st *temp;
    char item;
    temp = top;
    item = top->ch;
    top = top->prev;
    **free(temp);** //here exception occurred 
    return item;
}
```

please help me to solve this and also can anyone suggest any suitable technique to solve issues like this by myself? Thank you.

Comment: [Stop using `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: The first `for` loop doesn't stop when it gets to the end of the string.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: `pop()` doesn't check if the stack is empty.

Comment: The `evaluate` function doesn't return an `int` as promised if `flag != 1`.

Comment: *"suggest any suitable technique"*: step through the code using a debugger, setting breakpoints, inspecting variables.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ex : abcba, so if arr[j] != pop(), then it will return zero otherwise the only case which is possible is flag = 1, which is return 1? Am i missing something?

Comment: @trincot but this exception error comes is while debugging itself:(.

Comment: I know, but with a debugger you can stop long before the error occurs and check what the state of the variables is, and see where the first point is where variables are not as expected, so finding the deeper cause of the exception that occurs some steps later.

Comment: @Barmar oh, i should have added "||" instead of &&, so sorry for such a silly mistake and thank you.

Comment: `&&` is correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true. But you need to add `&& arr[i] != '\0'`

Comment: @NishuPatel You may be correct, but it's so confusingly written that even compilers warn about it. Instead of `if (flag == 1) { return 1; }` just write `return flag == 1;` or even `return 1;` since it's never supposed to get there if `flag` is not `1`.

Comment: @trincot i even tried adding breakpoints earlier, but whenever I press enter after writing input array/string, debugger directly jumps to that error part without waiting for any breakpoint

Answer (score 3):

I will show you a generic way of approaching these kind of problems. I will not even try to say it is a good one, but it works for me in general and worked here in the first run, at least for the few tests I ran.

(This is a long post because I am building the example using copy and paste from the code and commenting).

### About the posted code

It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. In general it is better to post a description of the task before the code. Reading the code I believe that:

- your target is the function `evaluate()`
- the idea is to check for a format wCwR, a string like "1234C4321"

  - there is a `C` or `c` at the center
  - if the string before `C` is reversed after the `C`, then `evaluate` returns `true`
- the use of a `stack` is by request.

Notes:

- do not use fixed values like `arr[100]`. It is easier to encapsulate things and use jus pointers
- do not write interactive code. It is far too slow and inconvenient. Use files, constants, factory functions.
- never ever use `gets`. It is deprecated for decades
- return `0`  for `false`
- never ever use a global thing
- write code to `free` (and test it) as you write code to `malloc` memory.
- `main` should be the first function of your code, if possible in a separate file.

#### where is the `stack`?

This is the `struct` from your code:

```
struct stack
{
  char ch;
  struct stack *prev;
} *top = NULL;
```

This is problematic and fragile.

- this is a `Node`. Not a `stack`. When programming things like stacks, lists, trees or similar *containers* it is safer to note that a container is a (possibly empty) collection of nodes. And each node contains (or points to) some data.
- **a stack is not a node. a node is not a stack**.
- this thing in your code is global. Solves no problem in general. You can have just one in your entire code. What if you need a pair of stacks? An array of stacks? A stack of structs?

#### a possible `Stack`

```
typedef struct st_node
{
  char            ch;
  struct st_node* prev;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
  unsigned size;
  Node*    top;
} Stack;
```

Here we have a stack of nodes. And some metadata in the stack itself: the size.

I will take this further into a complete example, with C code and output. I am copying and pasting from the program as we go.

#### the stack is not the task

We need a stack implementation. But we do not want in no way to mix the program and the code for stacks, since

- we can get this in the language or from someone else or from a library
- if we really need to write code for a stack we want to keep it separated in order to be able to use it in other programs

#### functions for a stack

We will want the bare minimum POP, PUSH and TOP operations, plus a constructor and a destructor. Let us consider:

```
Stack* create();
Stack* destroy(Stack*);

char pop(Stack* stack);
int  push(char c, Stack* stack);
char top(Stack* stack);
```

Using pointers makes it trivial to write for 1 or 1,000 stacks in code. And as in `C++` RAII concept we will write first `create` and `destroy`.

#### possible code for `create` and `destroy`

```
Stack* create()
{
    Stack* stack = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if (stack == NULL) return NULL;
    stack->size = 0;  // empty
    stack->top  = NULL;
    return stack;
}
```

Nothing fancy: we allocate a stack and set it empty by making `size = 0`.

(Off-topic: Bear in mind that there is a cult in C that says to not use casts in `malloc()`. I will do. Ever. As a reminder to the programmer and the readers. Even a really simple code like this allocates memory for `Node` or `Stack` as you will see. The compiler does not need this casts but by writing and repeating it you can be sure of what is what and prevent many errors and save you for much trouble. The kind of trouble that costs money and jobs and time.)

(This cult is based on a never updated book from the '90s and some Usenet posts from even before. In areas like network programming or text editing is common to allocate memory for many types of buffers in few lines of code, and even the expression that goes to `malloc()` is a function call that evaluates the size of the buffer we need. In this way a cast like a clear note to us of what is what. Compiler do not need casts, but also does not have salary).

```
Stack* destroy(Stack* stack)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return NULL;  // no stack
    while (stack->size > 0)
    {
        Node* prev = stack->top->prev;  // save
        free(stack->top);               // destroy top
        stack->top = prev;              // reassign
        stack->size -= 1;
    }
    free(stack); // now the stack 
    return NULL;
}
```

Just the expected, but the fact that each stack has its own `size` makes things simpler. Navigate the stack free'ing the nodes and then `free` the stack. Why return always `NULL`? This is just to make it possible to reset the pointer in the same line. Every day thousands of programs crashes for the use of invalid pointers. We want no margin for this.

This program can be run already:

```
int main(void)
{
    Stack* one = create();
    one   = destroy(one);  // destroy stack, clear pointer
    return 0;
}
```

Just for moral support.

#### `top`

TOP is really simple: just return the value at the top of the stack, left the stack unchanged: a single line

```
char top(Stack* stack)
{  // return char in the top, or negative value
    if (stack == NULL) return -1;
    if (stack->size == 0) return -2;
    return stack->top->ch;
}
```

#### `pop`

POP removes the element at the top and returns it to the caller:

```
char pop(Stack* stack)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return -1;
    if (stack->size == 0) return -1;
    char  top  = stack->top->ch;    /// save it
    Node* temp = stack->top;        // save the pointer
    stack->top = stack->top->prev;  // go back
    stack->size -= 1;               // 1 less
    free(temp);
    return top;
}
```

As expected, saves the element, reassign the top, `free` the node, adjust the size, just a few lines.

#### `push`

```
int push(char c, Stack* stack)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return -1;
    Node* nw = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (nw == NULL) return -1;
    nw->ch     = c;
    nw->prev   = stack->top;
    stack->top = nw;
    stack->size += 1;
    return 0;
}
```

PUSH is a matter of creating a node and linking it at the top of the stack.

#### `show`: a helper function

In general stacks does not have a method to show its contents, except for testing. But sure we are testing, so:

```
int show(Stack* stack, const char* msg)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    if (stack->size == 0)
    {
        printf("    stack is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("    %d elements in stack:\n\n", stack->size);
    Node* p = stack->top;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < stack->size; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%8d,'%c' [%3d]\n", 1+i, p->ch, (int)p->ch);
        p = p->prev;
    }
    printf("-----\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This version gets an optional title, very convenient in testing. See the examples.

#### 'str_to_stack`

```
int str_to_stack(const char* str, Stack* stack)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return -1;
    if (str == NULL) return -2;
    const char* p = str;
    while (*p != 0)
    {
        push(*p, stack);
        p++;
    };
    return 0;
}
```

This is just a way to push a string into a stack. In one line. So we can write code as:

```
    Stack* one = create();

    str_to_stack("Stack", one);
    show(one, "\"Stack\" added =>");

    str_to_stack(" Overflow", one);
    show(one, "\" Overflow\" added =>");
```

just to see

```
"Stack" added =>    5 elements in stack:

       1,'k' [107]
       2,'c' [ 99]
       3,'a' [ 97]
       4,'t' [116]
       5,'S' [ 83]
-----
" Overflow" added =>    14 elements in stack:

       1,'w' [119]
       2,'o' [111]
       3,'l' [108]
       4,'f' [102]
       5,'r' [114]
       6,'e' [101]
       7,'v' [118]
       8,'O' [ 79]
       9,' ' [ 32]
      10,'k' [107]
      11,'c' [ 99]
      12,'a' [ 97]
      13,'t' [116]
      14,'S' [ 83]
-----
```

This is way better than a loop or an interactive code...

### The stack files

#### `stuff.h` the stack header file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct st_node
{
    char            ch;
    struct st_node* prev;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    Node*    top;
} Stack;

Stack* create();
Stack* destroy(Stack*);

char pop(Stack* stack);
int  push(char c, Stack* stack);
// helper function to show stack contents
int show(Stack* stack, const char* msg);
// helper function to put a string in a stack
int  str_to_stack(const char* str, Stack* stack);
char top(Stack* stack);
```

#### `stuff.c` the stack implementation

```
#include "stuff.h"

Stack* create()
{
    Stack* stack = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if (stack == NULL) return NULL;
    stack->size = 0;  // empty
    stack->top  = NULL;
    return stack;
}

Stack* destroy(Stack* stack)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return NULL;  // no stack
    while (stack->size > 0)
    {
        Node* prev = stack->top->prev;  // save
        free(stack->top);               // destroy top
        stack->top = prev;              // reassign
        stack->size -= 1;
    }
    free(stack);  // now the stack 
    return NULL;
}

int push(char c, Stack* stack)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return -1;
    Node* nw = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (nw == NULL) return -1;
    nw->ch     = c;
    nw->prev   = stack->top;
    stack->top = nw;
    stack->size += 1;
    return 0;
}

char pop(Stack* stack)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return -1;
    if (stack->size == 0) return -1;
    char  top  = stack->top->ch;    /// save it
    Node* temp = stack->top;        // save the pointer
    stack->top = stack->top->prev;  // go back
    stack->size -= 1;               // 1 less
    free(temp);
    return top;
}

int show(Stack* stack, const char* msg)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    if (stack->size == 0)
    {
        printf("    stack is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("    %d elements in stack:\n\n", stack->size);
    Node* p = stack->top;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < stack->size; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%8d,'%c' [%3d]\n", 1+i, p->ch, (int)p->ch);
        p = p->prev;
    }
    printf("-----\n");
    return 0;
}

int str_to_stack(const char* str, Stack* stack)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return -1;
    if (str == NULL) return -2;
    const char* p = str;
    while (*p != 0)
    {
        push(*p, stack);
        p++;
    };
    return 0;
}

char top(Stack* stack)
{  // return char in the top, or negative value
    if (stack == NULL) return -1;
    if (stack->size == 0) return -2;
    return stack->top->ch;
}
```

So we can include the header in any program and just compile `stuff.c`

#### A complete test

```
int main(void)
{
    Stack* one = create();

    str_to_stack("Stack", one);
    show(one, "\"Stack\" added =>");

    str_to_stack(" Overflow", one);
    show(one, "\" Overflow\" added =>");

    printf("TOP is '%c'\n", top(one));
    show(one,"stack now: ");

    // copy to another stack
    Stack* other = create();
    printf("Reversing a stack into another\n");
    while (one->size > 0) push(pop(one), other);

    show(other, "new stack (reversed): ");
    show(one, "original (should be now empty): ");
    one = destroy(one);  // destroy stack, clear pointer
    other = destroy(other);  
    return 0;
}
```

This program

- creates `one` a stack
- pushes the string "Stack"
- shows the stack contents
- pushes the string  `Overflow`
- show TOP of stack
- creates `other`, a second stack
- copy `one` to `other`
- lists both stacks
- destroys both stacks

#### output

```
"Stack" added =>    5 elements in stack:

     1,'k' [107]
     2,'c' [ 99]
     3,'a' [ 97]
     4,'t' [116]
     5,'S' [ 83]
-----
" Overflow" added =>    14 elements in stack:

     1,'w' [119]
     2,'o' [111]
     3,'l' [108]
     4,'f' [102]
     5,'r' [114]
     6,'e' [101]
     7,'v' [118]
     8,'O' [ 79]
     9,' ' [ 32]
    10,'k' [107]
    11,'c' [ 99]
    12,'a' [ 97]
    13,'t' [116]
    14,'S' [ 83]
-----
TOP is 'w'
stack now:     14 elements in stack:

     1,'w' [119]
     2,'o' [111]
     3,'l' [108]
     4,'f' [102]
     5,'r' [114]
     6,'e' [101]
     7,'v' [118]
     8,'O' [ 79]
     9,' ' [ 32]
    10,'k' [107]
    11,'c' [ 99]
    12,'a' [ 97]
    13,'t' [116]
    14,'S' [ 83]
-----
Reversing a stack into another
new stack (reversed):     14 elements in stack:

     1,'S' [ 83]
     2,'t' [116]
     3,'a' [ 97]
     4,'c' [ 99]
     5,'k' [107]
     6,' ' [ 32]
     7,'O' [ 79]
     8,'v' [118]
     9,'e' [101]
    10,'r' [114]
    11,'f' [102]
    12,'l' [108]
    13,'o' [111]
    14,'w' [119]
-----
original (should be now empty):     stack is empty
```

#### what about `evaluate()`

Now we have a stack we can use. Let us change `evaluate` to

```
    int is_wcwr(const char* str)
```

A function that returns `1` if `str` is a string in the expected format.

#### a possible implementation

```
int is_wcwr(const char* str)
{
    if (str == NULL) return 0;
    // size must be odd
    size_t size = strlen(str);
    if (size % 2 == 0) return 0; // false
    // must have 'c' or 'C' in the center
    size_t pivot = size / 2;
    if ((str[pivot] != 'c') && (str[pivot] != 'C'))
        return 0;
    Stack* stack = create();
    // put 2nd half into stack
    str_to_stack((const char*) str+pivot+1, stack);
    // now compares 1st half of string with stack contents
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pivot; i+=1)
    {   // pair is ch_l ch_r
        char ch_l = *(str + i);
        char ch_r = pop(stack);
        if (ch_l != ch_r)
        {
            stack = destroy(stack);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    stack = destroy(stack);
    return 1;
}
```

The logic is simple and there is no need in fact for a stack. But we can use one for sure.
Invariants:

- the length of the string must be odd
- at the center we have `c` or `C`

So

- we create a stack and push the second half of the string into the stack.
- compare the values in the stack with the values in the string as long as they are equal
- return as soon as a difference is found

#### A test program

```
int main(void)
{
  const char* res[]    = {"is not", "is"};
  const char* test[] = {
      "123456C654321",
      "23456C654321",
      "",
      "test",
      "tests",
      "tects",
      "teCts",
      "xyzCzyx"
  };

  const unsigned N = sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]);

  printf("Total of %d strings to test\n", N);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
      printf(
          "\t\"%s\" %s in the wcwR format\n",
          test[i], res[is_wcwr(test[i])]);
  return 0;
}
```

This code permits entering test strings at the top and running the code. A single loop. No reads, no files.

#### output

```
Total of 8 strings to test
        "123456C654321" is in the wcwR format
        "23456C654321" is not in the wcwR format
        "" is not in the wcwR format
        "test" is not in the wcwR format
        "tests" is not in the wcwR format
        "tects" is not in the wcwR format
        "teCts" is not in the wcwR format
        "xyzCzyx" is in the wcwR format
```

### Complete code

#### `main.c`

```
#include <string.h>
#include "stuff.h"

int is_wcwr(const char*);

int main(void)
{
    const char* res[]    = {"is not", "is"};
    const char* test[] = {
        "123456C654321",
        "23456C654321",
        "",
        "test",
        "tests",
        "tects",
        "teCts",
        "xyzCzyx"
    };
    const unsigned N = sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]);

    printf("Total of %d strings to test\n", N);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        printf(
            "\t\"%s\" %s in the wcwR format\n",
            test[i], res[is_wcwr(test[i])]);
    return 0;
}

int is_wcwr(const char* str)
{
    if (str == NULL) return 0;
    // size must be odd
    size_t size = strlen(str);
    if (size % 2 == 0) return 0; // false
    // must have 'c' or 'C' in the center
    size_t pivot = size / 2;
    if ((str[pivot] != 'c') && (str[pivot] != 'C'))
        return 0;
    Stack* stack = create();
    // put 2nd half into stack
    str_to_stack((const char*) str+pivot+1, stack);
    // now compares 1st half of string with stack contents
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pivot; i+=1)
    {   // pair is ch_l ch_r
        char ch_l = *(str + i);
        char ch_r = pop(stack);
        if (ch_l != ch_r)
        {
            stack = destroy(stack);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    stack = destroy(stack);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Actually  I'm in college (sem3) and our professor taught us like this(node = stack only) or maybe he is trying to teach us basic first. Thank you so much sir for giving such a long explanation and for your time.

Comment: Well, as I said, this is problematic and leads to much more work. a stack is a possibly empty list of nodes. A node in your case contains a `char`. In the example I wrote may be you saw how having your model closer to this makes things easier. _basic_ should not be more difficult.

Comment: This looks like a very helpful post. Quick bit of feedback though, re "It is not clear to me what you are trying to do". On Stack Overflow it is ideal to understand the problem space fully before posting. A large proportion of new questions are difficult to understand, and of those, a substantial proportion are immediately abandoned by the OP, and requests for clarification go unanswered. So a answer that replies before those clarifications may be "wrong" even if it is generally helpful.

Comment: A good trick to answering here is to avoid having the OP in mind when one answers - think of the general/future reader instead. Where one does that, meta-commentary about the OP, or the quality of the question, or requests for clarification/action become automatically pointless; this is great, since we probably don't need those things anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is not occuring where you think it's occuring. You're not checking for an empty stack when popping, i.e. `top == NULL`. Then you are trying to de-reference `NULL` with `top->ch`.

There are other issues with the code. Use `fgets()` instead of `gets()`, which is deprecated. There is no return value at the end if `flag == 0` (which it can if there are no characters after the "c" or "C"). Just `return flag;` without the `if`. Your `for` loop can run off the end of the string, since you're not checking for `\0`. You are not checking the return value of `malloc()`.