C Program to remove empty lines
I wrote the following C program to remove any empty lines from a text file "LINES.txt".
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp, *ft;
    fp = fopen("LINES.txt", "r");
    ft = fopen("TEMP.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL || ft == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(ft);
        exit(1);
    }

    int e_flag = 0;
    char ch, c[100];
    int i = 0;
    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch != '\n' || ch != '\r')
        {
            c[i] = ch;
            i++;
            if (c[i] != ' ' && c[i] != '\t')
                e_flag = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            c[i] = '\0';
            if (e_flag == 1)
            {
                fputs(c, fp);
                e_flag = 0;
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ft);
    remove("LINES.txt");
    rename("TEMP.txt", "LINES.txt");
    printf("\nFile editing complete\n");
    return 0;
}

The code seems to compile well with no error or warnings. However, when I try to run it on codeblocks with GCC, I get the message "Program stopped working".
I cannot understand what's going on wrong here.
The same can be easily achieved by using fgets() instead of fgetc(). However the challenge is to use fgetc().
Thanks in advance.

As far as I know, it's not safe to call fclose on NULL file handles, so firewall your "Cannot open file" handling e.g if (fp != NULL) { fclose(fp); fp = NULL; }.

The first error I can see is if(ch!='\n'||ch!='\r'). This condition always holds. I didn't try to understand the logic any further.

Don't call fclose with a NULL pointer. Not your issue if the files are opening successfully but a definite problem if one or both do not. ch should be an int and there's nothing to stop i from going past 99.

If you were to run this in a debugger you could easily see where the problem is and what is happening.

You may want to read these two links: 1. How to debug small programs 2. What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

You are not writing anything to ft.

Another to readw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true

Instead of reading the file character by character, read a whole line with fgets(). Then you can check if the line is empty. If not, write it to the output file.

Even if you fix the logic error and use the correct handle to write to TEMP.txt your problem will remove all '\r' and '\n' not just empty lines.

You don't guard against overflow on c[i]

fgetc() returns an int not a char.

You either have to know the maximum line length (currently hard-coded to 100 and not checked), dynamically resize c (like getline() would do for you) to read an entire line, or use fseek() to remember start of line then look ahead to find end of line; if there was only spaces skip the line otherwise go back to beginning of line with fseek() and now print it.  You could also mmap the file to accomplish the look-ahead.

Actually, you should also tells what line terminators you want to support. You handle eol ("\r\n"), unix ("\n"), legacy mac ("\r").  Some or all? If you want dos and unix but not mac how do you want to handle a "\r" that isn't followed by "\n"?

You should define what you mean with an empty line.  Is a blank line (with space and tab) empty?

@Barmar speaks with wisdom. Just declare a sufficient buffer, read with fgets() and check if the first character in the buffer is '\n'. If it is -- the line is empty. That seems far easier than a character-oriented read. Say your line can never be more than 1023 characters. All you need is char buf[1024]; while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) { if (*buf == '\n') { puts ("empty line"); } } That can be the entire main() to spit out "empty line" each time one is encountered.

This is a slight modification of your code.  One of the most significant issues I discovered is that the original code was writing to the input file. That could result in some serious undefined behavior and program fail.
Another modification is that I introduced the switch() statement. To me,
switch() presents the ideal method for interrogating every char read from
the file.  It makes understanding and flag-setting very clear, imo.
Your mileage may vary.
Also added some error-checking.  More error-checking could be added, and I've highlighted in comments at least one such place.
Please see comments in the code for more detail in general.   This code will read an input file and exclude blank lines from the output file as it goes.
Code is compiled and tested by me only minutes ago.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Note: some files have lines longer than 100 chars. Update this value if needed: */
#define BUFF_SIZE 100 

int main()
{
    FILE *fp_in = fopen("LINES.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp_out = fopen("TEMP.txt", "w");
    int i=0, ch, e_flag = 0;
    char c_buff[BUFF_SIZE+1];

    if (fp_in == NULL || fp_out == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
        if(fp_in)
            fclose(fp_in);
        if(fp_out)
            fclose(fp_out);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((ch = fgetc(fp_in)) != EOF)
    {
        switch(ch)
        {
            case '\n': /* newline */
                if(e_flag == 1)
                {
                    /* Code comes here if we have a newline and it
                    * is Not the 1st char of the line.  Else, it 
                    * would be a blank line and we don't want 
                    * to write blank lines.*/
                    c_buff[i++] = (char)ch;
                    c_buff[i] = '\0';

                    /* This is one reason I changed the file pointer 
                    * naming  convention...
                    * ... to add clarity and ease trouble-shooting. 
                    * Original  code was  writing to the input file.  
                    * Pretty sure That wasn't desired. */
                    fputs(c_buff, fp_out); /* Write to OUTPUT file */
                    i = e_flag = 0;
                }
            break;

            /* Exclude these from buffer/output *unless* the line 
            * contains other char types too: */
            case '\r': /* carriage return */
            case '\t': /* tab */
            case ' ':  /* space */
                if(e_flag == 1) /* Not the only character type on the line? */ 
                    c_buff[i++] = (char)ch;  /* A: yes. OK, add to buffer. */
            break;

            default:  /* all other chars: */
                e_flag = 1; /* Line contains chars that are Not just a 
                            * newline, tab, space, etc...
                            * Flag this line as a 'go' for OUTPUT */
                c_buff[i++] = (char)ch;  /* ALWAYS add default chars, */
            break;
        }
        if(i > BUFF_SIZE-2)
        {
            printf("Need a larger buffer for this file!!\n");
            printf("Buffer has %d chars.\n", i);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp_in);
    fclose(fp_out);
    remove("LINES.txt");
    /* Should check to ensure remove() is successful before the rename().
    * Left as an exercise for OP...*/
    rename("TEMP.txt", "LINES.txt");
    printf("\nFile editing complete\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

