Check for table null in jQuery for JSON response
I have a JSON Response which has 5 tables. So I parse that same JSON. After parsing, I am getting 1st table as [] . So I want to check that condition. Below is the JSON response and parsing.


var dataResponse = JSON.parse(response);
var NE_length_Data = "";
if (dataResponse != null || dataResponse != undefined) {

  var FSAInfoData = dataResponse.Table; // UG
  var FSAInfoData1 = dataResponse.Table1; // MDU
  var FSAInfoData2 = dataResponse.Table2; // AR
  var FSAInfoData3 = dataResponse.Table3; // vendor
  var FSAInfoData4 = dataResponse.Table4; // history
  var FSAInfoData5 = dataResponse.Table5; // progress data

  $("#spnFiberEngFsaId").text(FSA_IDNew);
  $("#spnProgressID").text(FSAInfoData5[0].JOB_PROGRESS_ID);

  var NE_LENGTH = FSAInfoData[0].UG_LENGTH + FSAInfoData2[0].AR_LENGTH; // Here I want to add condition to check null for 1st table
  $("#spnFiberEngFsaLength").text(NE_LENGTH.toFixed(4));

}



Due to this null not checked my code is not getting further executed. What can I try next?

|| should be &&

JSON.parse() can never return undefined; if the parse fails it raises an exception. Why do you think you need to check that?

@Barmar:  I just added that as a condition for validation, will remove it if not required.!!

The problem is that the combined condition is always true. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true

But this has nothing to do with your actual problem. If you're getting [] then that's the value in the JSON.

@Barmar : is that ok if (dataResponse != null) ???

Shall I put whole JSON for your reference ?

Please post a minimal example, not something extremely long.

If you want to check the condition use if (FSAInfoData.length > 0) { ... }

here is the jsfiddle, check the first Table https://jsfiddle.net/Lenb2uys/

I misunderstood the question, I thought you didn't expect an empty array. If you just need to check if it's empty or not, use .length like I said above.

ok, let me try and check

Check the length before trying to index into the array.
var NE_LENGTH = (FSAInfoData.length == 0 ? 0 : FSAInfoData[0].UG_LENGTH) + FSAInfoData2[0].AR_LENGTH;

So if the length of the first table is 0, this defaults to 0 instead of FSAInfoData[0].UG_LENGTH.
Another method is to use optional chaining to prevent the error when trying to access the property of a nonexistent element, and ?? to supply the default value.
var NE_LENGTH = (FSAInfoData[0]?.UG_LENGTH ?? 0) + FSAInfoData2[0].AR_LENGTH;


Thanks Barmar for your  help..!! It saved a lot of time for me.
